# MongoDB find by key name (not value)

Tags: mongodb

So I have a key value object

```
project {
    name: "",
    createdBy: "some object id",
    
    
    sharedWith: {
       //here is a key value object to find by name
       "645c9bfe68c1438ef182bc26": { write: true }
    }
}
```

So I have to find all projects by key name, that project sharing with.
My request to this

I am doing it this way, and I have to apply some query filters to $or operator

```
return this.readProjectsQuery({
      $or: [{ createdBy: userId }, { ??? }],
    });
```

Comment: Storing any data as fields/keys is problematic and is considered a MongoDB _anti-pattern_.  Can you change your data model to be something like `"sharedWith": [ { "sharer": "645c9bfe68c1438ef182bc26", "write": true}, ... ]`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs unfortunately, I can't )) This model was created before me, and Team Lead asked me do not change it )

Comment: Is `project` a field within a MongoDB document? I suppose `readProjectsQuery` is some class or class instance method?  How does it translate to a MongoDB query?

Comment: Yeap, project is a field of the mongo document

Comment: Would you show some sample documents and the desired query results?  Your query logic is not completely clear to me.

Comment: @rickhg12hs 
projects_collection:

{
     name: '',
     created_at: number, //timestamp
     project: {
 sharedWith: {
       //here is a key value object to find by name
       "645c9bfe68c1438ef182bc26": { write: true } //i need to point my request to //name of the key
    }
     }
}

Comment: Are you looking for something like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EDp8RKFkKZp)?

Comment: @rickhg12hs looks like it solves the problem. Make an answer with the solution and I will mark it as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project's class or class instance method `readProjectsQuery` is unknown to us, but based on your shown data model and comments, you can find the documents you are looking for using a MongoDB query like this.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    {"project.createdBy": ObjectId("000000000000000000000001")},
    {"project.sharedWith.645c9bfe68c1438ef182bc26": {"$exists": true}}
  ]
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EDp8RKFkKZp).

Answer (score 0):

You may review your data model, using dynamic field names is a poor design. You can use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { sharedWith_KV: { $objectToArray: "$sharedWith" } } },
   {
      $match: {
         $or: [
            { createdBy: "some object id" },
            { "sharedWith_KV.k": "645c9bfe68c1438ef182bc26" }],
      }
   },
   { $unset: "sharedWith_KV" }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IXcdaLbnzJI)